# (Very) simple static site generator with template for non-blog site

Tags: static-site-generator

**[Please see update at the bottom.]**

A couple of years ago I made a homepage using only a free HTML template. It is, of course, fully manual and very simple. The content is text pages and one or two photo pages.

I now want to automate the site with a static site generator. The problems are:

1. The options I've been finding are too complicated, above all because they are aimed at creating blogs. For example, the engines Jekyll or Hugo are good for blogs, but to use them for simpler non-blog sites one would need to learn quite a lot.
2. 99 % of the themes available are with a sidebar, multiple columns, cards, or other decorations. I am just looking for a column-style theme, which would also be modern and responsive. Kind of:

   - menu (the dark/light mode option would be good but not obligatory)
   - main text, generated using Markdown
   - footer

The principal structure of my site is like this:

```
/index
/cats/index.html
/cats/feeding.html
/cats/mating.html
/dogs/index.html
/dogs/photos.html
/dogs/grooming.html
etc.
```

What would you recommend?

---

**Update: I have found a good static HTML generator for those with very limited knowledge of CSS and HTML - it is called [Yellow](https://datenstrom.se/yellow/). Good luck.**